# Chromeのデベロッパーツールみたいな

Tags: vscode

Chromeのデベロッパーツールみたいなアドオンはありますか？ライブプレビュー側を選択したらコードの方にフォーカスされるような機能です。

Comment: まず VS Code にはデフォルトでは HTML のライブプレビュー機能がありません。おそらく [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) か何か拡張機能を既に利用なさっていると思うので、いま何をお使いなのか [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

この回答を投稿した時点では preview 状態の拡張機能ですが、[ms-vscode.live-server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) (Live Preview) には devtools を起動する機能として `Live Preview: Show Debug Preview` があります。これは外部のブラウザでページを開きつつ devtools を触れる機能です。